# Cisco ASA - terminal a single Lan-to-lan VPN session

Tags: vpn, cisco, cisco-asa

On a Cisco ASa how can a single lan-to-lan VPN tunnel be terminated?  "vpnsession-db logoff l2l" will end all lan-to-lan sessions, and it doesn't accept parameters to control which session is ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sh vpn-sessiondb l2l`

Locate the index of the session you want to disconnect, then

`vpn-sessiondb logoff index <session_index>`

Comment: Thanks, I thought that was for "remote" VPN connections only but now I look again I see they share a common pool of indexes.